# Laravel 5.3 Seeder - undefined method table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

I'm trying to learn Laravel, but it seems the documentation is written with faulty examples... I want to create a table migration, run it, and seed it with some content.

First:

```
php artisan make:migration create_projects_and_tasks_tables
```

With the following content:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProjectsAndTasksTables extends Migration
{
    /**
      * Run the migrations.
      *
      * @return void
      */
      public function up()
      {
          Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
              $table->increments('id');
              $table->string('name')->default('');
              $table->string('slug')->default('');
              $table->timestamps();
      });

      Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
          $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
          $table->string('name')->default('');
          $table->string('slug')->default('');
          $table->boolean('completed')->default(false);
          $table->text('description');
          $table->timestamps();
      });
  }

  /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tasks');
        Schema::drop('projects');
     }
}
```

It migrated Ok. So I want to seed the projects table.

First:

```
php artisan make:seeder ProjectsTableSeeder
```

The contents:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProjectsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $projects = array(
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Project 1', 'slug' => 'project-1', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Project 2', 'slug' => 'project-2', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime],
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Project 3', 'slug' => 'project-3', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime]
        );
        DB::table('projects')->insert($projects);
    }
}
```

All set, I tried to rollback the migration, migrate and seed it:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
Rolled back: 2016_09_28_160459_create_projects_and_tasks_tables
Rolled back: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Rolled back: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated: 2016_09_28_160459_create_projects_and_tasks_tables

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                   
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::setTable()
```

And that's it. My table is empty, and the method DB::table() seems to not exist anymore in the framework, even if the 5.3 docs shows it. What can I do?

I'm using the Laravel Homestead vagrant box, so php version or composer isn't the issue. I'm also using MySQL as my database driver.

Comment: Try: php artisan make:seeder --class=ProjectsTableSeeder

Comment: Maybe `use DB;` ? Did you change a DatabaseSeeder.php file?

Comment: Put a back slash in front of `\DB`.

Comment: Something wrong with syntax in CreateProjectsAndTasksTable

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax in CreateProjectsAndTasksTables, it migrates and rolls back nicely with no errors at all. Also, I used the boilerplate Laravels generates and just added extra fields to the table, following the manual.

Comment: @Chintan7027 there is no --class option.

Comment: php artisan help db:seed

Answer (score 1):

Once you have written your seeder classes, you may use the db:seed Artisan command to seed your database. By default, the db:seed command runs the DatabaseSeeder class, which may be used to call other seed classes. However, you may use the --class option to specify a specific seeder class to run individually:

```
php artisan db:seed

php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder
```

Also You Can provide a seeder class reference to call method of DatabaseSeeder.php file

**php artisan db:seed**

will run the DatabaseSeeder.php file and invoke the run() meothd

So here you can provide list of Seed source like follow

```
public function run()
{
     $this->call(CountriesTableSeeder::class);
     $this->call(VendorTypesTableSeeder::class);
}
```

Reference : [seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding)

Comment: this shouldn't be an answer

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `--seed` option when passed to the `migrate:refresh` command will run

`{YOUR_APP}/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`

The `make:migration` artisan command will create your seed, but it won't add the seeder to the DatabaseSeeder.php file. You'll need to manually do this.

However, if you want to specify a particular seeder with `migrate:refresh`, then use the `--seeder=YourSeeder` option.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the top of your seeder class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Somehow, DB is not within the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error. This was caused by typo obviously. Try to compare all the dataseed tables with other tables. You might have put \DB::class instead of \DB::table.